# How to optimize VBA Code for comparing information

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, compare

The code is doing everything that I need it to. It's taking much too long though upwards of a couple minutes to complete the macro. How can I optimize this VBA code to run quicker?

I'm new to VBA and I'm not quite sure how to proceed. This code will be running on roughly 35,000 lines of data.

I have a feeling it's because my loop is not running on an array?

```
Public Sub matchRow()

    Dim dumpSheet, activeSheet, outputSheet As Worksheet
    Dim startRow, outputRow, tempDumpRow, tempActiveRow, activeRowCount, finishedActiveIndex As Integer
    Dim finishedActive() As String
    Dim isExist As Boolean

    Call OptimizeCode_Begin

    'Set sheets
    Set dumpSheet = Sheets("Dump")
    Set activeSheet = Sheets("Active Directory")
    Set outputSheet = Sheets("Output")

    'Set start row of each sheet for data
    startRow = 5
    outputRow = 5

    'Get row count from Active Depository sheet
    activeRowCount = activeSheet.Range("B5:D5").End(xlDown).Row

    'Set index
    finishedActiveIndex = 5

    'Re-define array
    ReDim finishedActive(5 To activeRowCount - 1)

    'Set the start row
    tempDumpRow = startRow

    'Here I looped with OR state, you can modify it to AND start if you want
    Do While dumpSheet.Range("B" & tempDumpRow) <> "" Or dumpSheet.Range("C" & tempDumpRow) <> "" Or dumpSheet.Range("D" & tempDumpRow) <> ""

        'Reset exist flag
        isExist = False

        'loop all row in Active Depository sheet
        For tempActiveRow = 5 To activeRowCount Step 1

            'If row is not finished for checking.
            If UBound(Filter(finishedActive, tempActiveRow)) < 0 Then

                'If all cell are equal
                If dumpSheet.Range("B" & tempDumpRow) = activeSheet.Range("B" & tempActiveRow) And _
                   dumpSheet.Range("C" & tempDumpRow) = activeSheet.Range("C" & tempActiveRow) And _
                   dumpSheet.Range("D" & tempDumpRow) = activeSheet.Range("D" & tempActiveRow) Then

                    'Set true to exist flag
                    isExist = True

                    'Store finished row
                    finishedActive(finishedActiveIndex) = tempActiveRow

                    finishedActiveIndex = finishedActiveIndex + 1

                    'exit looping
                    Exit For

                End If

            End If

        Next tempActiveRow

        'Show result
        outputSheet.Range("B" & outputRow) = dumpSheet.Range("B" & tempDumpRow)
        outputSheet.Range("C" & outputRow) = dumpSheet.Range("C" & tempDumpRow)
        outputSheet.Range("D" & outputRow) = dumpSheet.Range("D" & tempDumpRow)

        If isExist Then
            outputSheet.Range("E" & outputRow) = ""
        Else
            outputSheet.Range("E" & outputRow) = "Item found in ""Dump"" but not in ""Active Directory"""
        End If

        'increase output row
        outputRow = outputRow + 1

        'go next row
        tempDumpRow = tempDumpRow + 1

    Loop

    'loop all row in Active Depository sheet
    For tempActiveRow = 5 To activeRowCount Step 1

        'If row is not finished for checking.
        If UBound(Filter(finishedActive, tempActiveRow)) < 0 Then

            'Show result
            outputSheet.Range("B" & outputRow) = activeSheet.Range("B" & tempActiveRow)
            outputSheet.Range("C" & outputRow) = activeSheet.Range("C" & tempActiveRow)
            outputSheet.Range("D" & outputRow) = activeSheet.Range("D" & tempActiveRow)
            outputSheet.Range("E" & outputRow) = "Item found in ""Active Directory"" but not in ""Dump"""

            'increase output row
            outputRow = outputRow + 1

        End If

    Next tempActiveRow

    Call OptimizeCode_End

End Sub




Sub OptimizeCode_Begin()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    EventState = Application.EnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    CalcState = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    PageBreakState = activeSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
    activeSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

End Sub
```

Comment: load the data into variant arrays and loop those, not ranges.

Comment: What's the `OptimizeCode_Begin` and `_End` code? Also, if you're looking to optimize, this might be a better question for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @BruceWayne -- I'm guessing they're from here:  https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/2/25/best-way-to-improve-vba-macro-performance-and-prevent-slow-code-execution

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables you are correct

Comment: Every time one pierces the veil of the worksheet, either to read or write, it slows down the code.  This happens regardless if the screen updates are turned on or off.  Limit the number of times this happens and your code will run quickly.  to do this load everything that needs to be referenced into a variant array.  Create a variant array for the output.  Then iterate the data array putting the desired output in the output array.  Then put the output array data in the desired output range.  This limits the number of times the veil is pierced to two not hundreds.

Comment: These `Dim dumpSheet, activeSheet, outputSheet As Worksheet` are only defining the last.

Comment: Try and avoid defining names that can cause confusion, like `activeSheet`

Comment: @nathan_Sav noted. I realized that after adding the optimization sub